# Render json instead of html with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Want to build a very simple app that both has some html pages but will allow for an api as the output is just some calculations done by js.

I want to render a json output from my controller and not render html file. Any ideas how to do so with angularjs?

Comment: You can't. I'm afraid you'll have to use a server-side language for that.

Comment: You do need a container to output json. Where are you planning to show it, like in a textarea or something like that?

Comment: I'd like it to return in this format: http://en.gravatar.com/jack.json

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify to output json from your controller. But still not sure where you will show it?

Comment: I created to plunker for us to have a better understanding. Can you please have a look? I believe it will help me to have a better understanding of your requirement. http://plnkr.co/edit/CWJbltSNPB0YYPnbnaig?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a JSON document will be a single request, where the returned content has content type `application/json`.

If you want Angular.js, which is a frontend library, you need to make a request for an HTML document (and render the necessary HTML markup in the process), then for the angular.js library. What is rendered afterwards is still HTML (content type: `text/html`).

So the answer is: no, you cannot do that with Angular.js.

You will need a server-side script to output a properly formatted JSON (and nothing else) and the correct `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a AngularJS module called [`json`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json). Use it as a filter in your output.

Usage (In HTML Template Binding):

```
{{ json_expression | json }}
```

Usage (In JavaScript):

```
$filter('json')(object)
```

Where the `object` is

> Any JavaScript object (including arrays and primitive types) to filter.

Example:

```
<pre>{{ {'name':'value'} | json }}</pre>
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "value"
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to just render or return just json and not the html. Your solution is still very much using html

Comment: You can use this filter without HTML. I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.